# Consulta MySQL Mesma Coluna Parametros Diferentes

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Opa, coisa simples, tenho uma tabela teste, orgao e estado

tabelas

```
teste = 'teste_estado_id_1'
        'teste_estado_id_2'
        'orgao_id'

orgao = 'orgao_id'

estado = 'estado_id'
```

Numa consulta preciso relacionar a tabela teste com suas duas colunas de estado com a tabela estado e a coluna orgao_id com a tabela orgao.

Tentei assim:

```
select
      *
from
    teste, estado, orgao
where
     estado.estado_id in(teste.teste_estado_id_1,teste.teste_estado_id_2) and
     orgao.orgao_id = teste.teste_orgao_id and
     teste.teste_ativo=1
```

Só que me retornaram dois registros, e deve ser apenas um.

Vlw

Comment: porque a tabela teste tem 2 campos id da tabela estado?

Comment: Opa, são necessários na tabela teste armazenar dois itens distintos da tabela estado, são campos inteiros

Comment: já tentou quebrar  o in em 2 instruções?

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo. vlw

Comment: `estado.estado_id = teste.teste_estado_id_1 or estado.estado_id = teste.teste_estado_id_2`